# Connect to server in iOS didRecieveAuthenticationChallenge not called?

Tags: ios, authentication, networking, nsurlconnection, basic-authentication

I am trying to connect to a server in an iOS app. Here is my code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{

    NSLog(@"This is happening");
    NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"user"
                                                                password:@"password"
                                                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
int code = [httpResponse statusCode];
NSLog(@"%i",code);

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", newStr);


}
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
NSLog(@"here...");

 return YES;

}
```

and this is in viewDidLoad:

```
NSString *url = @"http://example.com:9999/";
NSURL * URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:URL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection self];
```

and this is in the header for delegates:

```
<NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
```

didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge is not being called, but didReceiveResponse is called and prints "401" and didReceiveData returns the text on the page "requires authentication".

didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge is never called, nor is canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace, so I cannot authenticate. How do I remedy this?

Comment: Is `canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace` called or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use https in your url instead of http for this method to be called.

```
NSString *url = @"https://example.com:9999/";
NSURL * URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:URL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection self];
```

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: Ah I see. The site I'm connecting too unfortunately does not have https setup, just HTTP. Is there an alternative way to connect to regular http?

Comment: Never made it work on HTTP only, and considering that with this authentication method (Basic Auth) your credentials are sent with every request, not encrypting it is a fairly big security hole

Comment: It is a huge security hole. I agree. We're just trying to see if it connects right now, thats the next step.

Comment: You can try AFNetworking here,it offers some convenience method to set Basic Auth headers on request ([httpClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:_username password:_password];)

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing a delegate

NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender